ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.nbextensions'
I try to run this command:
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
and get this error:enter image description here
Could you please help me? I need to install posit jupyter notebook extension to publish to posit connect.
Best regards

Please read How do I ask a good question?, especially the 'Search and Research' sections and 'Help Others Reproduce the Issue' where it emphasizes that screenshots are not adequate. Just past in the error report in a fenced code block when posting, if a posting is warranted because what you tried from other posts about the topic failed to address your particular issue. What version of Jupyter are you trying to use? The contributor extensions don't work in current versions of Jupyter Notebook (version 7+) or JupyterLab. Plus, in those tech ...

 that is no longer how you install extensions. Usually you can now just do it at the pip or Anaconda/conda level, depending on what is primary package manager.

Maybe you can try to downgrade the notebook like pip install notebook<7.

The main point of my comment was the author wasn't telling us the version. You assume, probably rightly so, they have a higher version, but we honestly don't know which makes it hard to advise appropriately.
